# On Facebook, can I find who my "most influential" friends are?

Tags: facebook, statistics

Is there an app for that?

It could be based on the number of posts they put and comments they receive and so on.  If it could include some network analysis, that would be also great.

If this is not available, what about someplace this data might be retrieved from?

Comment: http://stupidtwitterstats.com/ is a similar fun app for Twitter

Answer (score 2):

You can use the app called [Wisdom](http://wisdom.com/what-is-wisdom/).

> Get a unique view of your network through cool stats from you and your
>   friends’ Facebook activity. You will be surprised by the results!
>
> With an interactive graphic display, find out who from your friends is
>   the most active, most communicative, most popular and most cheerful.
>   Easily identify who interacts with you the most, and whom you are most
>   closely connected to. And analyze how your network evolves over time.

[image]

Comment: It seams like Wisdom is not available any more :(

Answer (score 0):

Try [ThinkUp](http://thinkupapp.com/docs/intro.html#who-thinkup-is-for).

> ThinkUp is a free, open source web application that captures your posts, tweets, replies, retweets, friends, followers and links on social networks like Twitter and Facebook.

...and provides interesting analysis.

Comment: The only problem is that it's a self-hosted web app -> `All you need is a web server that can run a PHP application.`